# Want to run the up-button only after api level 11

Tags: android, android-activity, up-button

I wants the up-button only on API level 11 and later, but my program need to run on all devices. How can i do this?

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

OR

Can I add up-button to all API levels?
Please advise...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check for the Android OS version install on the device with this:

```
int currentAPIVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

if (currentAPIVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

    // RUN THE CODE SPECIFIC TO THE API LEVELS ABOVE HONEYCOMB (API 11+)   
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

You would have to run this check in every Activity part of your app and perhaps, also provide an alternative when the API level is below 11.

There will however be a disparity in the UX for users on different API levels on their devices. To bridge this, you could consider looking at the [ActionBarSherlcock Library](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) that will help you bring parity to your app regardless of the API level (2.x and above).

**UPDATED:**

To add an action to the Home Button that will go back to the previous `Activity`, override the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method as shown below. Note the use of `android.R.id.home` in the code. You can add additional *cases* to the switch block if you have additional menu items that will be shown in the `ActionBar` in the same `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case android.R.id.home: {
        this.finish();

        return true;
    }

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i add some action to that button.

Comment: @AlexChengalan: To the Home button?

Comment: @AlexChengalan: Please check the updated answer. I hope this is what you meant. If I am wrong in thinking that, let me know.

Comment: How about if we want to move to parent activity, that we have mentioned in `Manifest` without using `finish()`?

Comment: @BugsHappen: You could invoke a new `Intent` and point it to the _parent activity_. You will also need to set a flag for the intent. For example: `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)` to clear the activity stack. You will still **need to call `finish()`** after the `startActivity(intent)`.

Comment: I have been using `NavUtils` to move back to parent without calling `finish()`. Does that mean that my application is keeping the children `Activity` in memory?

Comment: @BugsHappen: If you are using NavUtils, then no. The flag I mentioned earlier is taken care of. I'm guessing, finish() is taken care of to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ActionBarSherlock - http://actionbarsherlock.com/ for what you need

Answer (score 0):

ActionBarSherlock is definitely what you need,check this out http://actionbarsherlock.com